# Completely Different prediction results from .h5 keras model and .json tensorflow.js model

Tags: python, node.js, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow.js

so, My model is giving me results with decent accuracy for test images

```
import cv2
from IPython.display import display, Javascript
from google.colab.output import eval_js
from base64 import b64decode

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
face_haar_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('/content/gdrive/My Drive/New FEC Facial Expression/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
from IPython.display import Image
try:
 filename = '/content/gdrive/My Drive/photo-1533227268428-f9ed0900fb3b.jpg'
 img = cv2.imread(filename)

 gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

 faces = face_haar_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3,6)
 print('faces', faces)
 for(x,y,w,h) in faces:
   cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
   roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
   roi_color = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
   plt.grid(None)
   plt.xticks([])
   plt.yticks([])
   imgplot = plt.imshow(img)
 # Show the image which was just taken.
 # display(Image(filename))
except Exception as err:
 # Errors will be thrown if the user does not have a webcam or if they do not
 # grant the page permission to access it.
 print(str(err))


import cv2
import sys

imagePath ='/content/gdrive/My Drive/photo-1533227268428-f9ed0900fb3b.jpg'
image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('/content/gdrive/My Drive/New FEC Facial Expression/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(
   gray,
   scaleFactor=1.3,
   minNeighbors=3,
   minSize=(30, 30)
)

print("[INFO] Found {0} Faces.".format(len(faces)))

for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
   cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
   roi_color = image[y:y + h, x:x + w]
   print("[INFO] Object found. Saving locally.")
   cv2.imwrite('/content/gdrive/My Drive/converted Images/faces.jpg', roi_color)

status = cv2.imwrite('faces_detected.jpg', image)
print("[INFO] Image faces_detected.jpg written to filesystem: ", status)
# from skimage import io
from keras.preprocessing import image
img = image.load_img('/content/gdrive/My Drive/converted Images/faces.jpg', color_mode = "grayscale", target_size=(48, 48))
x = image.img_to_array(img)
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis = 0)
x /= 255
show_img=image.load_img('/content/gdrive/My Drive/converted Images/faces.jpg', grayscale=False, target_size=(200, 200))
plt.gray()
plt.imshow(show_img)
plt.show()
if len(faces): 
 custom = model.predict(x)
 index = np.argmax(custom[0])
 emotion1 = custom[0][index]*100
 print(custom)
 print(emotion_label_to_text[index],' => ',  emotion1)
else:
 print('No Face Detected')
```

This is giving good results and the output for the same result is correct, the image I inserted was happy image and opencv is used to detect the face and crop it then use that cropped image to put into the model and is giving me good results,

But the tf.js part I converted keras model to .json using tfjs converter and I wrote following code

```
 const classifier = new cv.CascadeClassifier(cv.HAAR_FRONTALFACE_ALT2);
    try {
        const canvImg = await canvas.loadImage(
            path.join(__dirname, `images/${req.file.filename}`)
        );
        const image = await cv.imread(path.join(__dirname, `/images/${req.file.filename}`));
        const classifier = new cv.CascadeClassifier(cv.HAAR_FRONTALFACE_ALT2);
        const { objects, numDetections } = classifier.detectMultiScale(image.bgrToGray());
        if (!objects.length) {
            return next({
                msg: 'No face detected'
            })
        } else {
            const model = await tf.loadLayersModel(
                "http://localhost:8000/models/model.json"
            );
            const obj = objects[0]
            const cnvs = canvas.createCanvas(48, 48);
            const ctx = cnvs.getContext("2d");
            ctx.drawImage(canvImg, obj.x, obj.y, obj.width, obj.height, 0, 0, cnvs.width, cnvs.height);
            var tensor = tf.browser
                .fromPixels(cnvs)
                .mean(2)
                .toFloat()
                .expandDims(-1)
                .expandDims(0, 'None')



            const prediction = await model.predict(tensor).data();
            console.log(prediction);
            var emotions = [
                "angry",
                "disgust",
                "fear",
                "happy",
                "sad",
                "surprise",
                        ];
            var index = Object.values(prediction).findIndex(
                (p) => p === Math.max(...Object.values(prediction))
            );
            res.status(200).json(emotions[index])
            fs.unlink(
                path.join(process.cwd(), "./faceDetection/images/" + req.file.filename),
                function(err, removed) {
                    if (err) console.log("file removing err");
                    else console.log("file removed");
                }
            );
        }

    } catch (e) {
        return next(e)
    }
```

I used opencv4nodejs for the detection of image, canvas to crop the image (canvas giving me good result for cropping the face part) and tf.js for predicting, But the output is giving me same results everytime where among all those keys in object one of them will get 1 (fear in this case) and keep giving me same result for the same image that I tested in keras.

Am I doing something wrong in manipulation of tensor?

Comment: Did you try to print the tensors to see if they are different for each prediction ?

Comment: yes, they are different for different images, but still giving me same results, or if not the same, then completely random and inaccurate results (which is faaaaar away from what my h5 model gives)

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason. In python you "normalize" your image input to [0,1] using `x /= 255`. You are not doing it in Javascript.

Comment: let tensor = tf.browser.fromPixels(cnvs, 1)

            const resized = tf.image.resizeBilinear(tensor, [48, 48]).toFloat()

            const offset = tf.scalar(255.0);
            const normalized = resized.sub(offset).div(offset);

            const batched = normalized.expandDims(0)

            const prediction = await model.predict(batched).data();
Yes now I used normalization (if this is correct) still giving me bad results

Comment: Still strange. Are you sure you need sub(offset)? This way your tensor will be negative.

Answer (score 0):

The preprocessing in js is different than the one in python.

In python the image is normalized by dividing it by 255

In Js the image is transformed to grayscale by computing the mean over the third axis (mean(2)). Here is what the tensor should be:

```
 const tensor = tf.browser.fromPixels(cnvs)
  .div(255)
  .toFloat()
  .expandDims(0)
```

Comment: the tensor you provide didnt changed to grayscale, You said sum(2) but where to add that?

Comment: It is mean(2) instead. When you compute mean(2) of an image it outputs a grayscale image.which is not what you want

Comment: yes I actually want the grayscale image because my model takes [null,48,48,1] input. So I need the grayscale you can see it in python code as well

Comment: Yeah, I missed that part before. Therefore, you can keep the `.mean(2)`. However, there are several ways to compute a grayscale; you need to know which one exactly is done by `plt` if you want to replicate the exact same functionality